# Embed android terminal emulator in my app

Tags: android, terminal-emulator

I noticed that this app could actually embed terminal emulator inside at (2.35)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGbBRaw_0Po

How can I do this? I know that one method is to embed by api like google maps. But how can I do for an apk like terminal emulator?

Comment: Tried reading the source code? https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator